# How to check OTG support in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, usb

When I was on Android I was able to check whether my device supports USB OTG or not using [this](http://beebom.com/how-check-usb-otg-support-android-phone/) procedure. I have heard that Windows 10 Mobile supports OTG but neither there is any official content about that nor I could find the list of Handsets that support OTG. So is there any way to check whether my phone is OTG compatible or not? My phone is 535 DS running W10M (14393.693).

Comment: You know, you don't really have to post a huge screenshot with your phone's About screen in every question. Most of the time, just the model and OS version/build are enough. Plus, posting your phone's IMEI on a public website might not be the best idea. Cheers!

Comment: I'll take care next time.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Lumia 535 dual Sim phone does not support OTG functionality. Me too have that phone. And can confirm that it can't support.

And to check the OTG support there isn't any app available in store which checks for OTG support in phone. Only via official documention of phone you check does a phone support OTG or not.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little? The question is how to check for OTG support in Windows 10 Mobile, not so much about whether a specific model supports OTG.

Comment: But he is asking for his phone. Specifically. And Lumia 535 won't support it.

Comment: See the title. But whatever, agree to disagree.

Comment: The way that I was able to check this was to use a OTG cable and plug in my mouse's USB dongle, and see if it picked up the mouse. It didn't even attempt to pick it up so that told me that my Lumia 930 doesn't support it.

It's a manual way of checking, and you'd have to have access to an OTG cable, but it's one way you could check it out yourself.